# Determining that a certain diffeomorphism of $\Bbb R^n-\{0\}$ is orientation preserving or not

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, orientation, smooth-functions

Consider the diffeomorphism $f:\Bbb R^n-\{0\} \to \Bbb R^n-\{0\}$ (whose inverse is itself) given by $x\mapsto x/|x|^2$.

How can we determine that $f$ is orientation preserving? For $n=1$ it is clearly orientation reversing, and also for $n=2$, but it seems not easy to compute its Jacobian determinant for large $n$, so I think there should be another method. Can I get a hint?

Comment: Is it really? What happens for $n = 1$?

Comment: @Arthur Oh clearly it is not orientation preserving when $n=1$. This question was actually asking whether the map is orientation preserving or not, and I just guessed that it would be orientation preserving. My bad

Comment: Well, consider what happens for $n = 2$, then. You could ask "_When_ is it orientation preserving?" That's an interesting question.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks I've made an edit.

Comment: Hint: you could use (generalized) spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate the derivative in one point only, since the sign of the Jacobian cannot change on the connected set on which the map is defined (because otherwise it would have a zero somewhere).

Now note that the restrtiction of the map to the unit sphere is just the identity, and that it's derivative, in $x$ with $|x|=1$, will map $x$ to $-x$.

From this you can easily get a diagonal representation of the derivative in $x \in  S^{n-1}$, which allows you to directly read off the sign of the determinant.

Comment: interesting. This explains (much more nicely) why I obtained an $n-1$ identity block, in my calculations, but how can you immediately deduce without any calculations, and just based on the form of $f(x)$ alone that the derivative at a point $x \in S^{n-1}$ will send $x$ (which I recognize is the normal vector to the sphere) to $-x$?

Comment: because right now, the way I see this is that for $x \in S^{n-1}$, $Df_x(x) = \dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} f(x+ tx)$ (the simple relationship between total and directional derivatives), but $f(x+tx) = \frac{x}{t+1}$, so the derivative at $t=0$ is $-x$, just as you claimed. I'm just wondering if when writing up this answer, you had a quicker approach to justifying this.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The map is a reflection about the $n-1$ sphere. So it will map radial lines going from the inside of the sphere to the outside into (the same) radial lines, just with the direction reversed. Just look at the image of the map $t\mapsto tx$ for some $x$ with $|x| =1$ and resist the  temptation to calculate its derivative ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the set $U:= \Bbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\}$ is open and connected, and the map $f:U \to U$ you defined is $C^{\infty}$. So, the function $\phi:U \to \Bbb{R}$ given as
\begin{align}
\phi(x) := \det Df_x = (\det \circ Df)(x)
\end{align}
is a composition of smooth maps hence smooth (in particular continuous). Also, since $f$ is a diffeomorphism, we know that $\phi$ is no-where vanishing. Thus, by the intermediate value theorem, the image of $\phi$ lies either in $(-\infty,0)$ or in $(0, \infty)$. To figure out which, all we have to do is calculate $\phi$ at a simple point, for example $\phi(e_1)$, where $e_1 = (1,0, \dots, 0)$. Now, note that the matrix of $Df_x$ consists of the various partial derivatives $\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$. These are easy enough to calculate (quotient rule):
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_x &= \dfrac{\lVert x\rVert^2 \delta_{ij} - x_i\left( 2x_j\right)}{\lVert x\rVert^4}
\end{align}
In particular, at $x = e_1 = (1, 0, \dots, 0)$, this reduces to
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_{x = (1, 0, \dots, 0)} &= \delta_{ij} - 2 \delta_{i1} \delta_{j1}
\end{align}
If you assemble this into a matrix, it is the following block diagonal matrix:
\begin{align}
[Df_x] &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & I_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
So, what is the determinant?

Comment: I had written a similar answer before, but I think it can be done even easier, without almonst any calculation. (Only the derivative in $x$ with length $1$ in direction of $x$ must be calculated...anyway, +1.